# Is there a way to add shadow behind the app bar action buttons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar, sliverappbar

I am using `SliverAppBar` widget with some background image behind it. Since the image I will load will be dynamic, sometimes it can have light colors and can cause the back button (or any other action button) to be hardly visible.

As you can see in the screenshot below, I gave a little shadow to the app bar title using `TextStyle` & `Shadow` widgets, so it is much more visible than the back button.

[image: Example image]

Comment: Using a universal color which works on most color is the only way ig.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use "elevation" here is the Flutter link for more clarification: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/elevation.html&ved=2ahUKEwiEpfiIn4TwAhWUH7cAHY9ECIwQFjACegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw0wCdyaVv3EA8ulVXXvaVMu

Comment: Thanks but "elevation" adds shadow behind the app bar, not behind the action buttons.

Comment: You can try this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583184/flutter-floatingactionbutton-shadow